# Simulating trackpad three/four-finger down using Hammerspoon or Karabiner-Elements

Tags: keybindings, mission-control, magic-trackpad

I am trying to simulate a three-finger (four-finger if the three-finger drag is enabled) trackpad swipe gesture using either Hammerspoon or Karabiner-Elements on macOS. The goal is to simulate the fingers down using one of mouse additional buttons (btn4/5) and drag the mouse for completing the action (move between spaces/open mission control).

I have explored both Hammerspoon and Karabiner-Elements, but I'm unsure how to achieve this specific functionality.
I would like to know if there is a way to simulate the trackpad gesture of a four-finger swipe using either of these tools ora combination of them. I'm open to alternative suggestions or approaches that can help me achieve it.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: There are already keys that launch App Expose and Mission Control.  Instead of reinventing the wheel, can’t you map those keys to the mouse buttons?  I know Logitech can do this.   I have my thumb button mapped to MC on my Logitech mouse.

Comment: Yes, Allan it is also a good option however I think that to move between spaces, which is my main goal, an option to simulate the fingers down wold be much more natural. Besides that, it could be a bit more useful if I can combine it with mouse dragging. Maybe a should consider a Logitech mouse. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: There are keyboard shortcuts for that, too: `Ctrl` and left/right arrow.  Trying to map gestures to a button seems overly complex.